# Facing problem in fetching all Preimages using rpc

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, substrate-node

At certain time, it shows this error.
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a RPC for testing? I guess this might be a JS limitation?

Comment: wss://wallet-l0.pstuff.net

Comment: This is not related to PJS but to the node configuration. The node placed a limit on the size of the RPC responses, and this entry exceeds that size, so it fails. Usually it's meant to avoid DDoS attacks.